# Fetch field name and insert into

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Boas, será que alguém me pode dar uma ajudinha?

Estou a tentar fazer um insert dinâmico, onde o utilizador escolhe em uma select box em que tabela vai inserir os dados. Mas gostaria que quando ele seleciona-se a tabela, aparecessem os respetivos fied names daquila tabela.

Deixo aqui o código que tenho:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: orange;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #000000;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #000000}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="welcome.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="welcome.php">Voltar</a></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
<br>
<br>
<?php
$mydbname = 'visteon';
$conn=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','visteon');

if(mysqli_connect_error($conn))
{
echo 'Failed to connect';
}


$options = '';

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW TABLES");
$column_name ='Tables_in_'.$mydbname;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$options .= '<option value="' . $row[$column_name] . '">' . 
$row[$column_name] . '</option>';


echo '<select name="users" onchange="showTables(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="0">Select a table:</option>';
echo  $options;
echo '</select>';

?>
<br>
<form method="post" action="processprodutos.php">
<label>Tipo</label>
<input type="text" name="Tipo">
<br>
<label>Quantidade</label>
<input type="text" name="Quantidade">
<br>
<label>Linha</label>
<input type="text" name="Linha">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Adicionar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Aguardo resposta,

Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter as colunas de uma determinada tabela no MySQL basta fazer o seguinte:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tabela;
```

As propriedades que lhe podem interessar serão:

> Field (*nome da coluna*)
>   Type (*tipo de dados da coluna*)

Depois só terá de construir uma grelha para as mostrar.

Comment: Queria mesmo era algo assim do género: Uma select box com que o user possa interagir de maneira a que escolha em que tabela quer inserir os dados, ao selecionar a tabela os campos/field name's atualizavam(mudavam) conforme a tabela escolhida. Será isto possivel? Se sim necessitava de ajuda. Obrigado